# MSWord .SaveAs vs .ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have a large Lotus Notes project, a small part of which uses Word to create PDFs.  In one piece, it pastes some text into a new Word document and saves as a PDF, like this:

```
Set wrdApp = createObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.documents.add()
Set selection=wrdApp.Selection
selection.InsertBefore(doc.body(0))
strSaveFilename = "HelloWorld.pdf"
wrddoc.Saveas strSaveFileName, 17
Call wrddoc.close(0)
Set wrddoc = Nothing
Call wrdapp.quit(0)
Set wrdapp = Nothing
```

and in another part of the same chunk, it opens a Word document and then saves it as a PDF, like this:

```
Set MCwrdApp = createObject("Word.Application")
McwrdApp.visible = true
Dim wrdDoc As Variant 'word document
strfilename = "HelloWorld.docx"
Set wrddoc = MCwrdApp.documents.Open(strfilename)
f2 = "HelloWorld.pdf"
wrddoc.ExportAsFixedFormat f2, 17, 0, 1 
wrddoc.close(0)
Set wrddoc = Nothing
Call Mcwrdapp.quit(0)
Set McwrdApp = Nothing
```

The problem I'm having is that since we upgraded to Office 2016, occasionally WINWORD.EXE gets left running and I have to kill it with Task Manager.  The last time it happened Word was started in the sub that does the copy/paste.  But that's not the question.  The question is, are there differences between using .SaveAs and .ExportAsFixedFormat in this scenario?  Why would the developer (not me) have used one in one place and the other somewhere else?

Comment: [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-exportasfixedformat-method-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has PDF/XPS specific options that are not available in `.SaveAs` and `.SaveAs2`. The example is using `wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen` for smaller file size and lower quality.